# How to find text after pattern match

Tags: go

I have been experimenting with pattern matching. There is one thing I can't seem to find an answer to : what is the string of text in your text buffer that comes after the matched text.

Comment: Is the question about using the facilities of the `regexp` package? If yes, you probably need the `*Index` family of its `regexp.Regexp` type: they return not the matched substring but rather the start+end position of it in the source string. Hence the text immediately following a match would be at `end+1`.

Comment: It's not clear what you're talking about. There are many ways to do pattern matching, but to answer your question, we must know exactly what you're doing. Please include relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp.FindIndex` in the Go standard library.

It returns a `[]int` containing the **start** and **end+1** index of a matched string, it returns `nil` if no match is found.

If you search a string and find a match stored in a variable `loc`, then:

- `str[loc[0]:loc[1]]` would return matched text.
- `str[loc[1]:]` would return everyting **after** the matched text.

Source: [Go Documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindIndex)

Good luck!